# ADAL 3 Token Persistence

Tags: xamarin.forms, adal

I am lost after reading to many posts on the web, and need some advice.
I use ADAL 3.17.1 in my Xamarin.Forms project. Now with ADAL3, the refresh token and the AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync are no longer available and are internally handled. But this Refresh token in stores in memory only and when IOS app goes in the background, or when the application is close and reopened, the user needs to log again.

Is is possible to let the user log once in the morning and keep the token valid for 8-10 hours?. And not asking to log in when the app start or resume in the next 8-10 hours? I can't find post on that. All posts are with use of Refresh token...

Here is the code in my Authenticator class that run in IOS:

```html
    public class Authenticator_iOS : IAuthenticator
    {
        public async Task<MultipleAuthResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string resource2, string clientId, string returnUri)
        {
            MultipleAuthResult multipleAuth = new MultipleAuthResult();

            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new CustomTokenCache());
            if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
                authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);

            var controller = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
            var uri = new Uri(returnUri);
            var platformParams = new PlatformParameters(controller);
            platformParams.PromptBehavior = PromptBehavior.Auto;
            

            try
            {
                multipleAuth.ResultBackEnd = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, uri, platformParams);      // Token for backend
                multipleAuth.ResultGraph = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource2, clientId, uri, platformParams);       // Token for Graph query
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return multipleAuth;
        }

        public void SingOut(string authority)
        {
            //Token
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
            {
                authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
            }


            //Webview cookie
            NSHttpCookieStorage CookieStorage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
            foreach (var cookie in CookieStorage.Cookies)
            {
                    CookieStorage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: There's isolated storage on iOS, so that should be available in a Xamarin class. The method that acquires the token has an overload that allows you to pass in a token cache object (that you first create and persist in isolated storage). The token is valid for one hour, then your next call to `.AcquireTokenAsync()` will make use of the refresh token from cache to get you a fresh token and refresh token without UI prompts.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I use an Authenticator class like ADAL3 need. The "cache" fonction work well in UWP and Android, but IOS keep asking for login.
I update the post with the code I use

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're initializing a new cache instance every time your method fires.

```cs
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new CustomTokenCache());
```

which renders this check moot:

```cs
if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
```

Just remove initializing `CustomTokenCache` altogether, i have a feeling it will persist by default.
Do this instead:

```cs
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(commonAuthority);

if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count() > 0)
{
    authContext = new AuthenticationContext(
        authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I change my code, but the same behaviour is happening when I close, restart or resume my IOS application. But when I need to push data to Azure, I send another sign in and for this time the authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count() return a context. I read somewhere (i can't find it back) that IOS11 put the AccessToken in the memory cache instead of local cache for security. This way the "refresh token" that ADAL handle automatically is lost after closing or resuming from the application... I do not find the solution yet...

Comment: I suggest opening a support case with Microsoft if you have a Xamarin support plan or try to find a Xamarin sample that ties in ADAL on iOS11, maybe there's a catch.

Comment: After opening an support case with Microsoft I got this answer: Keychain is not directly supported by ADAL on Mac OS X. The default caching implementation will keep around tokens for the life time of the process, but they will not be persisted. If you wish to persist tokens you must implement the ADTokenCacheDelegate and provide it on AuthenticationContext creation.... I can't found anything on that for a c# Xamarin.IOS project. Any idea?